# How can I normalise a JavaScript object to a DOM element with YUI3?

Tags: javascript, dom, yui3

YUI2's Dom.get accepts both a DOM element *or* an id string as a parameter. In YUI3, Y.one is the replacement for Dom.get but it only accepts CSS selectors, not DOM elements. Is there a simple way, using YUI3, to normalise a JavaScript object to a DOM element?

Comment: That's not entirely correct. YUI 3's `Y.one` returns a `Node` instance whereas YUI 2's `Dom.get` returns a raw DOM element reference.

Comment: @SimonLieschke to get the raw DOM element you can use [Y.Node.getDOMNode(node)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_getDOMNode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support the same signature as `YAHOO.util.Dom.get` you could do something like this:

```
var getNode = function(el) {
    return Y.one('#' + el) || new Y.Node(el);
};
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/wrumsby/ysjwS/) of the function above in use.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API docs for Y.one](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_Y.one) it does accept a DOM element.

> node  a node or Selector

I think you can also pass a YUI 3 Node to it too. The only thing it doesn't do that DOM.get did is accept an id that isn't a CSS selector (e.g. 'foo' instead of '#foo').