# How to convert a JavaScript object to a YUI 3 node?

Tags: javascript, object, yui3

In my HTML I have something like this

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delete(this);"/>
```

and in the JavaScript file I define my function "delete" like this:

```
YUI().use('node', functioin(Y) {
   function delete(el){
       //Here is the problem
       el.get('parentNode');
   }
}
```

The problem is, I want to convert the "el" object (which is a normal JavaScript object) to a node of [YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library) 3 so that I can use YUI 3's functions more conveniently. And I don't know how to do it.

What is the solution?

Comment: OK, i found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892051/how-can-i-normalise-a-javascript-object-to-a-dom-element-with-yui3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YUI 3’s `Y.Node` constructor can simply take in a DOM element or selector string and return a new `Y.Node` instance:

```
// returns a Y.Node instance wrapping a div DOM element
var node = new Y.Node(document.createElement('div'));
```

**But**, the preferred way is the use the convenient `Y.one` factory method:

```
// returns a Y.Node instance wrapping a div DOM element
var node = Y.one(document.createElement('div'));
```

Also, YUI 3 has a `Y.NodeList` class which represents a collection of `Y.Node` instances:

```
// returns a Y.NodeList representing all divs on the page
var divs = new Y.NodeList(document.getElementsByTagName('div'));

// or using the convenient Y.all NodeList factory method:
divs = Y.all(document.getElementsByTagName('div'));

// …and finally the preferred way to do this using a selector string:
divs = Y.all('div');
```

In generally, use [`Y.one`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_Y.one) and [`Y.all`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_all) to rerun a [`Y.Node`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html) and [`Y.NodeList`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/NodeList.html) instance respectively; this is how you will see YUI 3 code written, and what all the examples will use.

For your specific use case of wanting to remove a DOM element which you already hold a reference to you could do the following using YUI 3’s `Y.Node` class:

```
// assumes el is a DOM element reference
Y.one(el).remove();
```